# passing a result(double type variable) from a method as an element of an array

Tags: c#, arrays, if-statement

***Background*** - 
I am new to programming in `C#` and am trying to code a custom indicator. On a trading platform that uses `C#`. A histogram with

```
positive Y axis =  reqAskArraySum
negative Y axis  = reqBidArraySum
```

The inbuilt compiler shows no errors. However the desired results do not seem to show up.
I know/it is possible there are some platform specific initialization problems i.e. code that I have not entered yet correctly.

***Question -*** 
The question here is with regards to the code posted below , which is a part of the whole code.
I would like to know whether the posted code satisfies the below objectives.

1. The objective here is to get a 'number' using a method.
2. Then only accept selected 'numbers' into an array. The selection/filtration is done by an 'If' statement

Any help and pointers would be highly appreciated.

```
         int i=0;
         double iAskSize = GetLevel2Size(ASK,0);   //GetLevel2Size(ASK,0) is the method that helps me to retrieve the ASK side 'numbers'//
         double iBidSize = GetLevel2Size(BID,0);   //GetLevel2Size(BID,0) is the method that helps me to retrieve the BID side 'numbers' //


         if(iAskSize>=AskTH_value)  //the number should be >= user defined AskTH_value, this is the filtration of the Ask Side 'numbers'//
```

> I am trying to get the filtered iAskSize 'numbers' into the array
>   reqAskSize, I believe there is a problem here. However I am not sure

```
         {
         double[] reqAskSize = new double[1000];

         double reqAskArraySum = 0;

         for(i=0;i<reqAskSize.Length;i++)
         {
         reqAskArraySum = reqAskArraySum + reqAskSize[i];
         }

         SetValue(0,reqAskArraySum);       

         }



         if(iBidSize>=BidTH_value)        **//the number should be >= user defined BidTH_value,this is the filtration of the Bid Side 'numbers'//**
```

> I am trying to get the filtered iBidSize 'numbers' into the array
>   reqBidSize, I believe there is a problem here. However I am not sure

```
         {
         double[] reqBidSize = new double[1000];

         double reqBidArraySum = 0;

         for(i=0;i<reqBidSize.Length;i++)
         {
         reqBidArraySum = reqBidArraySum + reqBidSize[i];
         }

         SetValue(1,-reqBidArraySum);      
         }
```

Comment: It is safe to ignore the 'SetValue' method as it is beyond the objectives of the question.
As 'SetValue' is platform specific and I am yet to fully figure it out.
Apologies for including it in the above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to add selected numbers into an array, once a number has been selected (through a conditional like if/else), the number should be set in the array.

For example

```
 int[] array = new int[6]; 
    for(int val = 0; val < 6; val++)
    {
    if(array[val] > 0)
    array[val] = 6; 
    }
```

Also to obtain a numeral, a return statement makes clear if anything is got. 
You should try and see where a return statement may belong within your code.